# Compare Long in java facing some issues

Tags: java, compare, equals, primitive-types

Following is my code to compare the Long values (I am sure this might irritate some one )

```
Long userRole = new Long(-1);

    userRole = 8;

    if ( userRole !=8 || userRole != 7)

                    {               
                        showSave = false;
                        request.setAttribute("VIEW", "N");
                    }

if ( userRole == 8 || userRole == 7) // this fails
```

all the cases becomes success.. :(

what i want to do is if the userRole is not equal to 8 and 7 then set the follwoing

```
showSave = false;
request.setAttribute("VIEW", "N");
```

i really dont get what is the mistake i make here.

thanks

Comment: maybe I'm missing something, Don't you mean `userRole !=8 && userRole != 7`? using '&&' instead of '||'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all this is not compile.

```
Long userRole = new Long(-1);
userRole = 8; // can't assign int to Long
```

You can change this to

```
serRole = (long) 8;
```

Or

```
userRole = 8L;
```

Then come to other part.

```
 Long userRole = new Long(-1);
 userRole = 9L;
 boolean showSave=true;
 if (userRole != 8&&userRole!=7) { // userRole is not equal to 8 and 7 then
     showSave = false;
 }
 System.out.println(showSave);
```

You should use `&&` not `||`

Out put:

```
 false
```

Answer (score 1):

First of All, You cannot assign int values to Long variables directly. To do so, then you need to type cast to Long type or need to add 'L' symbol to int literal. Find the modified code below

serRole = (long) 8; or serRole = 8L;

Your question is " if the userRole is not equal to 8 and 7". We have to write the "userRole is not equal to 8 and 7" in java as (userRole != 8 && userRole != 7).

'&&' represents "And"

'||' represents "Or".

So, working functionality of your code is as follows,

Long userRole = new Long(-1);

userRole = 8L;

boolean showSave=true;

if (userRole != 8&&userRole!=7) {

```
 showSave = false;
```

}